# Why do we celebrate Eid-Ul-Fitar?

Tags: eid

Assalam Wa Allaikum

Forgive my insufficiency of knowledge about my own religion

I have tried asking many Maulwi from our place but never have received any satisfactory answer

please share your knowledge

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell what I understood from my practice!

Before Eid-Ul-Fitr, we accomplish a mission which is one of the 5 pillars. So on that day it is a mission-complete-fest given to us by Almighty Allah. Allah wants us to be happy on that day because we have completed one of the greatest task given by him to us, which was understanding and suffering the pain of the poor. That is why we are even ordered to give Zakats. `It is not a must that Zakat has to be paid within Ramazan only. Can be paid any time of a year`

**NOTE**: It is not welcomed to visit graves of loved ones on eid days as well which is a proof that Allah doesn't like to be sad on eid.

> ***So conclusively***, Before both Eids we do a ritual which are parts of the five pillars of Islam. So both the Eids are gifted by Almighty
>   himself to celebrate. To spread the love and happiness.

Comment: i had pretty much the same idea , thanx for your answer

Comment: You are welcome brother :) Much appreciated if you select this as an answer. I shouldn't be asking though.

Comment: I upvoted already man , i am waiting for others to also share their knowledge ,give it some time :) :) :)

Comment: thumbs up :) :)